Algorithm to maximize total number of filled bins
I am looking for an algorithm that optimizes for the most total bins packed given a list of items and bin requirements.
Suppose I have a list of people represented by their specialty:
[Math, Math, Sales, Ops, Admin, Admin]

And I have multiple departments with job specialty needs:
Marketing: Sales, Admin
Engineering: Ops, Math
HR: Admin
Accounting: Math, Admin
Supply Chain: Math

To fill these roles in an efficient bin packing scenario, the choice would be
Marketing, Engineering, Accounting (a total of 3)

but in this scenario, I'm looking for the most total bins packed (4):
Marketing, Engineering, HR, Supply Chain

Is there a known algorithm that optimizes for this task?

Look up the Knapsack Problem

Can you see how many roles you're missing (in your case, 1 Admin, 1 Math) call these the vacancies. Then efficiently packing the vacancies will result in the most bins without a vacancy (full bins).

@paddy I'm familiar with the problem. Haven't found anything that addresses my specific use case. If you know of a version of the knapsack problem that answers this question, please expound.

@NeilButcher, the data set is multiple thousands of roles with multiple potential permutations for each role. It's not as easy as the example. I'm currently using a maximum weighted bipartite model to assign them, but it only focuses on optimizing the most roles being filled and not the most groups.

Would sorting the bins by size and packing in them in order work? Pack as many of the "size 1" bins as possible. Then take the remaining people forward and attempt to pack "size 2" bins and so on until all people are used?

I'm not sure if I understood the problem formulation correctly. Does each of the people have exactly one speciality or a secletion of the specialities? To me, the problem looks more like a bipartite matching problem, where the people are one partition and the roles are the other partition. @dancassin please be more specific on your usage of the term group in your comment.

@Codor, for the real data set, each person can have multiple specialties and each role can accept fuzzy matching, and I mentioned in a previous comment that I'm currently using bipartite matching. I'm unsure how to define groups any better than the example in the original question. The groups (e.g Marketing, HR, etc.) have roles that need to be filled. I need to maximize the total number of groups with all roles filled. Bipartite matching doesn't address this directly, but I think NeilButcher made sense suggesting to sort the groups and have the model fill the groups with fewest roles first.
